# How do I sign my SG4 out of google play?

Tags: google

I have tried several times to go to settings>accounts>google, however, when I touch google, my phone tells me repeatedly that "Unfortunately, settings has stopped".  Can someone help me please?  I really need to sign out of that old account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Log into it from another device's Web browser, change the password on that account, and go to https://mail.google.com and scroll to the bottom and select Details then Sight out other sessions.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/gmail/zIVuCmZ-tuA